# process structure memory allocation in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, structure

EDIT:

```
Typedef struct SPro{
     int arrivalTime;
     char processName[15];
     int burst;
} PRO;
```

I have an array of type PRO

```
PRO Array[100];
PRO enteringProcess;
//initialize entering process
```

then I need to creat a new process and allocate memory for that process using malloc Then point the pointer from the array to the memory chunk that malloc returns.

```
PRO *newPro = (PRO *) malloc (sizeof(PRO));
newPro = enteringProcess;
ProArray[0] = *newPro;
```

It seems that I'm doing something wrong since my program crashes at run-time.
Any help? thanks!

Comment: Where does the program crash? In the code above? How is PRO defined? Sorry, but for me the above snippets contain too few information.

Comment: How is enteringProcess declared? Is it also a pointer?

Comment: I'm so lost and confused even after the edit :) Time to go sleeping...

Comment: I guess it would be useful to see a bit more of your code, or at least know where you think the program crash. But from what I see, there is already a problem with the "newPro = enteringProcess;" statement. What is this "enteringProcess" variable? Because in the next statement, you're dereferencing "newPro" which is really "enteringProcess". Moreover, "ProArray" is an array of "PRO" not an array of "PRO*", which seems to be what you really want. So again, more details would be welcome.

Comment: It would be best if you posted the actual code which compiles rather than the mis copied code in the Q which does not. Please use the clipboard for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you need an array of *pointers* to PRO:

```
PRO *Array[100];

PRO *newPro = (PRO *) malloc (sizeof(PRO));
/* ... */
Array[0] = newPro;
```

I don't know what that `enteringProcess` is, so I cannot give opinion. Just that you should not assign anything to `newPro` other than the return of `malloc` or else you will leak the new object.

Comment: Why an array of pointers? The assignment Array[0] = *newPro copies the value at the adress pointed to by newPro in the variable Array[0]. This assignment is correct.

Comment: It is syntactically correct, but pointless. Creating a dynamic object just to use it just as the source of an assignment? If this is your need, you should use an automatic (aka local) variable. Or even better, initialize the object directly into the array. My guess was that if he was using `malloc` is because he needed the object to be dynamic.

Comment: I agree, the code is somewhat confusing. As I said in my answer, I don't see the point of the newPro pointer.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you need to allocate memory, the declaration

```
  PRO Array[100];
```

Already allocated the memory -- that is assuming your definition of PRO is something like;

```
  typedef struct {
     .....
  } PRO;
```

Revieweing your code;

```
// Declare a new pointer, and assign malloced memory
PRO *newPro = (PRO *) malloc (sizeof(PRO));

// override the newly declared pointer with something else, memory is now lost
newPro = enteringProcess;

// Take the content of 'enteringProcess' as assigned to the pointer, 
// and copy the content across to the memory already allocated in ProArray[0] 
ProArray[0] = *newPro;
```

You probably want something like this instead;

```
  typedef struct {
     ...
  } PRO;

  PRO *Array[100]; // Decalre an array of 100 pointers;

  PRO *newPro = (PRO *) malloc (sizeof(PRO));
  *newPro = enteringProcess;  // copy the content across to alloced memory
  ProArray[0] = newpro; // Keep track of the pointers
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing enteringProcess points to an invalid place in memory.

```
newPro = enteringProcess
```

is your problem.